# Is there a Ruby equivalent to Perl's Data::Rmap?

Tags: ruby, perl, recursion, nested, language-comparisons

Perl's [Data::Rmap](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-Rmap) allows you to recursively evaluate a BLOCK over a list of data structures (locally setting $_ to each element) and return the list composed of the results of such evaluations. $_ can be used to modify the elements.

This is useful for iterating over things like nested hashes, or hierarchies of arrays of hashes and the like.

Comment: **See also:** python tool that does something similar https://stackoverflow.com/tags/marshmallow/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby's `Enumerable` does everything you want, I think.  "... and return the list composed of the results of such evaluations" indicates you want `Enumerable#map`.  My first go would be something like this:

```
[ {...}, {...}, {...}, ... ].map do |hash|
  hash.something
  do_other_stuff_with(hash)
  hash                  # important to have as last line b/c of how #map works
end
```

Comment: AFAICT, this is not equivalent, because Data::Rmap works with more than just ArrayOfHash (AoH). It can also iterate more complex structures such as ArrayofArray (AoA), HashofArray (HoA), and others (AoAoH), (HoHoA) and so forth ad-infinitum.

Comment: .map will happily work on Arrays of things other than Hash.  What it won't do is recursion.  Perhaps a Y-combinator is in order?

Answer (score 1):

Without really looking into details, I'm not sure you need a module for that in Ruby.  Iterators and blocks are there to do what you want.

Comment: Edit to post an example or a link to an example by chance?

Comment: Check Gaius' answer, it has more details :)